# How do I get Tomato to use IPv6

Tags: ipv6, tomato

My ISP provides native IPv6 and it works great when I connect directly with my macbook to the ethernet port. I get a ipv6 assigned and all IPv6-only sites works great.

But when connecting through my Netgear WNR3500L router (running Tomato Firmware v1.28.7496-Toastman) IPv6 enabled sites won't work.

How would I configure my router for this to work? I don't have any "assigned/routed prefix" which the "native ipv6" settings in Tomato require, nor did I receive any settings from my ISP (it just worked).

Answer (score 1):

If your service provider is TekSavvy:

1. Register for IPv6 Services by going to `www.teksavvy.com/ipv6`, which will supply you with a new login address and credentials
2. Configure Tomato Router:

   1. Bssic > IPv6
   2. Select DHCPv6 with Prefix Delegation
   3. Prefix length: `64`
   4. Set up a DNS, such as `2620:0:ccc::2`, `2620:0:ccd::2`, and `2001:4860:4860::8888`
   5. Accept RA from WAN
3. To correct a Tomato Bug where random forward routes are generated:

   1. Administration > Scripts > WAN Up
   2. Paste the following:

      ```bsh
      echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/`nvram get wan_iface`/accept_raip -6 route flush default dev `nvram get wan_iface`echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/`nvram get wan_iface`/accept_ra
      ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Most of this is not likely to be relevant. The only important bit is to turn on DHCPv6 prefix delegation. That will get IPv6 passed through the Tomato router to end devices.

Comment: In case anyone is trying to decipher the mangled "Pasted the following:" command, it should read `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/\`nvram get wan_iface\`/accept_ra && ip -6 route flush default dev \`n
vram get wan_iface\` && echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/\`nvram get wan_iface\`/accept_ra` (I tried to edit the answer, but it said the edit queue was full.)